# converter swift2 to swift3 doesn't return correct?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

i want to converte my code source from swift 2.3 to swift 3
but i can't , plaese you can help me??

[image]

```
for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)

            switch trans.transactionState {

            case .purchased:
                let prodID = buyingProduct
                switch prodID {
                case ?adsid:
                    print("remove ads")
                    defaults.set(true, forKey: "adsremoved")
                    didbuyad = true
                case ?levelsid:
                    print("add levels to account")
                    self.unlockAllLevels()
                default:
                    print("IAP not setup")
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as!
SKPaymentTransaction)
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            case .failed:
                print("buy error")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as!
SKPaymentTransaction)
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            default:
                print("default")
                break;

            }
        }
    }
```

doesn't return correct value

Answer (score 0):

simply you just remove "?" from case.

```
for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .purchased:
            let prodID = buyingProduct
            switch prodID {
            case adsid:
                print("remove ads")
                defaults.set(true, forKey: "adsremoved")
                didbuyad = true
            case levelsid:
                print("add levels to account")
                self.unlockAllLevels()
            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as!
                SKPaymentTransaction)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .failed:
            print("buy error")
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as!
                SKPaymentTransaction)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            print("default")
            break;

        }
    }
```